# ¿Cómo crear una ventana movible que seleccione unos cuantos elementos de un dataframe?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código que me crea un dataframe de 3 columnas y 100 filas.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

fila1=list(np.arange(0,100))
fila2=list(np.arange(0,100))
fila3=list(np.arange(0,100))
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['one']=fila1
df['two']=fila2
df['three']=fila3
print(df)
```

Necesito crear una ventana que seleccione dos columnas, pero que se pueda mover de izquierda a derecha o viceversa en todo el dataframe y pueda calcular el promedio de todos los elementos seleccionados.

Comment: Una ventana? Qué ventana? con PyQt? con TKinter? que has intentado? Por favor añade más detalles a tu pregunta.

Comment: @Christian De las 3 columnas por ejemplo seleccionar las columnas 1 y 2, después extraerle su media a todo, lo mismo para las 2 y 3, seleccionarlas y luego extraer su media a todo.

Comment: @Christian que esta seleccion se pueda mover por el dataframe

Comment: Y ¿Qué has intentado? Por favor agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento. Aquí no hacemos tareas/proyectos, es necesario que muestres un esfuerzo por resolver tu propia pregunta.